i have a problem in importing and using bcrypt for hashing a password in my project
I tried to use bcrypt to hash a password in my project, but every time the password is saved in the MongoDB without being hashed. I've attempted various solutions, but none have worked. In an effort to diagnose the issue, I isolated the bcrypt function and tested it separately. However, I encountered an error of "relative references" ... bcrypt doesn't require a relative reference in the import statement to function properly. I'm unsure why I'm encountering this error.

the error : "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
"bcrypt". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or
"../"."

import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

const testPassword = "test123";
const saltRounds = 10;

bcrypt.hash(testPassword, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error hashing password:", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Hashed password:", hash);
    }
});


Import bcrypt like this:
import * as bcrypt from "bcrypt";

Then you should be able to call bcrypt.hash(...)
Edit: Ensure you have installed bcrypt too:
npm I bcrypt


i install and import bcrypt correctly but still not working...that's the problem !! every thing looks good in the code i check it many time

what is still not working ? The import or the password hashing ?
